# I am creating a RPS program. I am new to python, I am trying to figure out how the while loop works. I want to know how to repeat and break while loop

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNsMj.png)

I am trying to break the while loop so I can do an "Play again" input so the loop will repeat if they want to play again, although im not sure how to break it to allow it to repeat. I do know that I can do an i+=1 in my current program to allow the loop to repeat but then it just infinitely repeats.

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  [edit] the question and add the full code as plain text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The code shown in your image only has one while-loop that will never be entered because immediately before it, you set `i = 1`. The loop requires `i > 1` if it's to do anything at all. However, if you set `i` to a value greater than 1, the loop will run indefinitely until you terminate the process, because `i` is never modified by the loop. The only thing the loop does is `print(i)`. It's unclear what you expect here. Everything that's to belong to the body of a loop must be indented one level deeper than the loop statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this but here are the two ways I mostly use

first is as Yash Shahi mentioned, use a `flag`

```
flag = True
while flag:
    # rock paper scissors logic
    # this is where all the code accepts user input and 
    # creating a random choice of RCP happens

    print("Do you want to continue: ")
    x = input()
    if x == "N" or x == "n":
        flag = False
```

second way is using a break statement

```
while True:
    # rock paper scissors logic

    print("Do you want to continue: ")
    x = input()
    if x == "N" or x == "n":
        break
```

Comment: We have existing answered questions teaching these techniques, so if this is what you interpret the OP as asking for, the appropriate action is a vote to close as duplicate. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, just to confirm if I understood you correctly. Because a similar question has been asked before, I should vote to close the question as it is a duplicate of a particular question. is that right?

Comment: Essentially, yes. For background on this policy, see https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/ posted by one of SO's founders, explaining how the rules about closing questions relate to the original impetus for creating the site.

Answer (score -2):

create a bool variable initialised to true, for example

```
playing= true;
```

then write the while condition like this

```
while(playing){}
```

now if the person presses y to play again continue else change playing to false
hope this helps.

Comment: This code looks like C++, not Python.